# Geodesic of cone

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

We have the parametrization $\varphi (u,v) = (u cos(v),usin(v),u)$ of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2,z>0$. Then :

$$E=2,F=0,G=u^2$$

$\textbf{Theorem :}$ A curve $\varphi(u(s),v(s))$ is a geodesic if and only if satisfy :

$$ u''(s) + \Gamma_{11}^1 (u'(s))^2 + 2 \Gamma_{12}^1 u'(s)v'(s)+ \Gamma_{22}^1 (v'(s))^2 = 0 $$
$$ v''(s) + \Gamma_{11}^2 (u'(s))^2 + 2 \Gamma_{12}^2 u'(s)v'(s)+ \Gamma_{22}^2 (v'(s))^2 = 0 $$

Then the equations are :

$$ u''(s) -(\frac{u}{2})(v'(s))^2 = 0 $$
$$ v''(s) + (\frac{2}{u})u'(s)v'(s) = 0 $$

If we solve the second equation we have :

$$ 2 log(u)=-ln(v')+C $$
$$ \implies u^2 = K\frac{1}{v'} $$

And replacing in the first equation :

$$ u'' u^3 = \frac{C}{2}, C>0$$

How I can solve this equation?

Comment: Clairaut's law is easier, unless you want a start from basics.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by $u^3$, multiply by $u'$ and integrate:

$$
u''u'=\frac C2u'u^{-3}
$$

and thus

$$
\frac12u'^2=-\frac12\frac C2u^{-2}+\lambda\;,
$$

$$
\frac{u'u}{\sqrt{2\lambda u^2-\frac C2}}=1\;,
$$

$$
\frac1{2\lambda}\sqrt{2\lambda u^2-\frac C2}=s+\mu\;,
$$

$$
u=\sqrt{2\lambda(s+\mu)^2+\frac C{4\lambda}}\;.
$$